# Windows 7 doesn't see DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, dvd

I have a computer where was Windows XP installed, and everything was working fine. I've recentrly reinstalled there Windows 7 - and there no sing of DVD drive in the system.

It is shown in POST (model GSA 4167B), but nowhere in the system.
Any suggetions?

UPD. The DVD drive isn't shown in Device Manager at all.

Comment: Try disconnecting the drive and booting into Windows, then reconnecting properly and booting again to see if the OS detects it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully resolved the issue. There are 3 IDE channels on my motherboard, so I switched some cables and got it working at the end.

It seems to me that there was an issue with master/slave switcher on some of the devices. But why all of them were working with XP - that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the driver is installed first and foremost using Device Manager.  Click Start and in the search box type Device Manager.

Verify the DVD drive is listed under DVD/CD-ROM drives.

If it is an shows a yellow exclamation, you will need to download the drivers from your computer manufacturer's website and install the drivers for Windows 7.  It may also be listed as an "Unknown Device" in which case you need to download the drivers also.